# How to fix PHP (shell_)exec() permissions for copy pasting?

Tags: php, linux, exec, copy-paste, shell-exec

The following command executed in PHP's shell_exec() function:

```
echo 'A' ; cp -v $original $destination ; echo 'B' ; whoami
```

Will output ABapache, but nothing else. The copy command does not seem to be working. ($original and $destination are replaced with the correct path).

I made the apache user the owner of the folders I'm using for the cp command. It still doesn't work, I tried chmodding and more, nothing seems to work.

Is it blocked within PHP to run the cp command?

Thanks!